# unable to place menu inside container in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Following is code to display vertical menu bar, and when i run code `dropdown` menu comes out of bootstrap `container`.

Can somebody help, how can i place div inside container.

Menu should be place only inside `container`, but in my case the `<div class="container">` doesn't expand.

```css
.mega-dropdown {
  border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
  position: relative;
}

.mega-dropdown.active:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  height: 86px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #77c04b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 21px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 21px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  box-shadow: 0 0 21px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.mega-filtered-search .mega-dropdown.active:before {
  border-color: #0083c9;
}

.mega-dropdown.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.mega-dropdown.active>i {
  color: #686868;
}

.mega-dropdown.active .mega-content {
  display: block;
}

.mega-dropdown.active .mega-content>.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}

.mega-dropdown>button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mega-dropdown>i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 0;
  color: #b7b7b7;
}

.mega-content {
  display: none;
  width: 690px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #77c04b;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -2px;
  z-index: 21;
  margin-top: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 21px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 21px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  box-shadow: 0 0 21px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.mega-filtered-search .mega-content {
  border-color: #0083c9;
  width: 304px;
}

.dropdown-wrap.active .mega-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-wrap .mega-content {
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.dropdown-wrap .mega-content>.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}

.mega-list>header {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #151515;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.mega-list>header i {
  color: #77c04b;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.mega-list ul {
  margin: 15px -30px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.mega-list ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.mega-list ul li:after {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: absolute;
  right: 33px;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.mega-list ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
}

.mega-filtered-search .mega-dropdown {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.category-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

.category-list>li,
.category-list>li>ul li {
  display: block
}

.category-list>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 50px 12px 65px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative
}

.category-list>li>a i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.category-list>li>a:after {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.category-list>li:hover>a {
  background: #FED700;
  color: #FFF
}

.category-list>li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.category-list>li>ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #FED700;
  padding: 0 0;
}

.category-list>li>ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #303E47
}

.category-list>li>ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  color: #303E47
}

.dropdown-wrap {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-wrap.active {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-wrap {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.dropdown-wrap {
  width: 370px;
}

.dropdown-wrap {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f0d8";
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0px -2px 0px #b7b7b7;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  line-height: 0;
  top: -2px;
}

.mega-dropdown-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.mega-dropdown-wrap .mega-dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 42px;
  max-width: 570px;
}

.mega-dropdown-wrap .mega-dropdown:before,
.mega-dropdown-wrap .mega-dropdown:after {
  display: none !important;
}

.mega-dropdown-wrap .mega-dropdown .mega-content {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  left: -1px;
}

.mega-dropdown-wrap .mega-dropdown .mega-content .category-list>li>ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="myGroup" class="container">
  <div class="row rowd">
    <h2 class="text-center">Select Category</h2>
    <hr/>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="row field-block">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
          <span class="required label"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
          <div class="mega-dropdown-wrap">
            <div class="mega-dropdown active">
              <button>Select Category</button>
              <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>
              <div class="mega-content">
                <ul class="category-list">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-motorcycle"></i>Vehicles</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Bus, van, truck</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Industrial&nbsp;Vehicle</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Motorcycle</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Bicycle</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Spare Parts &amp; Accessories</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Mobile&nbsp;&&nbsp;Computer</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Computer&nbsp;&&nbsp;Laptop</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">tablets</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">iPads</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cc-diners-club"></i>Home&nbsp;Appliances</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">TV-Audio-Video</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Ac</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Washing&nbsp;Machine</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Fridge</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Camera&nbsp;&&nbsp;Lense</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Kitchen&nbsp;Accessories</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Game-Entertainment</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-building"></i>Real&nbsp;Estate</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">For Sale</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">For Rent</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Fashion</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-co"></i>Furniture</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Sofa&nbsp;&&nbsp;Dining</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Bed&nbsp;&&nbsp;Wardrobes</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Home&nbsp;Decor&nbsp;and&nbsp;garden</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Kids&nbsp;Furniture</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">other&nbsp;furniture</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="adicon-bell"></i>Jobs</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Data Entry & Back Office</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">BPO and Telecaller</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Sales and Marketing</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Operator and Technician</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Cook</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">IT Engineer and Developer</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Designer</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Reception and Front Office</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Accountant</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Teacher</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Other Jobs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="adicon-hat"></i>Services</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Driver and Taxi</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Electronic Repair</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Computer Center</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Health and Beauty</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Gym and Fitness</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Sports and Equipment</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="adicon-dog"></i>Pets</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Dogs</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Cats</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Food & Accessories</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Other Pets</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="adicon-heal"></i>Education</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Online&nbsp;Tutorials</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Tution</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="adicon-smile"></i>Matrimony</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">I&nbsp;Aa&nbsp;Male</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">i&nbsp;am&nbsp;female</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="adicon-hearts"></i>Note&nbsp;&&nbsp;Coin</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Note</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Coins</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="bor"></div><br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I get it right, you want the top level menu items to be shown initially and then on clicking any of them you want to show the sub-menu under the clicked item exactly under the clicked item.

If that is the case you could use the "data-toggle" and "data-taregt attributes as shown below" to achieve this effect.

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">        
        <li><a href="#" id="btn1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu" aria-expanded="false">Toggle Me</a>
            <ul class="nav collapse" id="submenu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn1">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is just and example, use this logic to further build the other menu items and they shall open right below the clicked item.